# Sequence match using Python

Tags: python, alignment, sequence

I am working on RNA sequence matching

```
seq = 'UCAGCUGUCAGUCAUGAUC'
sub_seq =['UGUCAG', 'CAGUCA', 'UCAGCU','GAUC']
```

I am matching the sub_seq to the seq, matched sub_seq is under the seq, if there is no matched, use dash line. Output looks like this:

```
UCAGCUGUCAGUCAUGAUC
UCAGCU--CAGUCA-GAUC
-----UGUCAG--------
```

I try to use the dictionary to do this

```
index_dict = {}
for i in xrange(len(sub_seq)):
    index_dict[seq.find(sub_seq[i])] = {}
    index_dict[seq.find(sub_seq[i])]['sequence'] = sub_seq[i]
    index_dict[seq.find(sub_seq[i])]['end_index'] = seq.find(sub_seq[i]) + len(sub_seq[i]) - 1
```

I cannot figure out the algorithm to do alignment, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
seq_l = len(seq)
for ele in sub_seq:
    start = seq.find(ele)
    ln = len(ele)
    if start != -1:
        end = start + ln
        print("-" * start + ele + "-"*(seq_l- end))
    else:
        print("-" * seq_l)

-----UGUCAG--------
--------CAGUCA-----
UCAGCU-------------
---------------GAUC
```

Not sure where `UCAGCU--CAGUCA-GAUC` comes from as you are only using a single sub sequence at a time in your code

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is because the output doesn't match what the OP wanted.

Comment: @jedwards, I went by the OP's own code. It is pretty trivial to do more if the OP actually needs to. just a matter of checking for non overlapping strings and fitting in accordingly

Comment: I agree for sure, I was just fielding a guess at the reason

Comment: The sub_seq is a single list with different sequence fragment, they are from experiment data. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll let me change your `index_dict` slightly, consider:

```
seq = 'UCAGCUGUCAGUCAUGAUC'
sub_seq =['UGUCAG', 'CAGUCA', 'UCAGCU','GAUC']

index_dict = {}
for i in xrange(len(sub_seq)):
    index_dict[seq.find(sub_seq[i])] = {
        'sequence':  sub_seq[i],
        'end_index': seq.find(sub_seq[i]) + len(sub_seq[i])   # Note this changed
    }
sorted_keys = sorted(index_dict)

lines = []
while True:
    if not sorted_keys: break
    line = []
    next_index = 0
    for k in sorted_keys:
        if k >= next_index:
            line.append(k)
            next_index = index_dict[k]['end_index']
    # Remove keys we used, append line to lines
    for k in line: sorted_keys.remove(k)
    lines.append(line)

# Build output lines
olines = []
for line in lines:
    oline = ''
    for k in line:
        oline += '-' * (k - len(oline))     # Add dashes before subseq
        oline += index_dict[k]['sequence']  # Add subsequence
    oline += '-' * (len(seq) - len(oline))  # Add trailing dashes
    olines.append(oline)

print seq
print '\n'.join(olines)
```

Output:

```
UCAGCUGUCAGUCAUGAUC
UCAGCU--CAGUCA-GAUC
-----UGUCAG--------
```

Note this is pretty verbose, and could be condensed a bit.  The `while True` and `for line in lines` loops could probably be merged into one, but it should help explain one possible approach.

**Edit**: This is one way you might join the last two loops:

```
seq = 'UCAGCUGUCAGUCAUGAUC'
sub_seq =['UGUCAG', 'CAGUCA', 'UCAGCU','GAUC']

index_dict = {}
for i in xrange(len(sub_seq)):
    index_dict[seq.find(sub_seq[i])] = {
        'sequence':  sub_seq[i],
        'end_index': seq.find(sub_seq[i]) + len(sub_seq[i])   # Note this changed
    }
sorted_keys = sorted(index_dict)

lines = []
while True:
    if not sorted_keys: break
    line = ''
    next_index = 0
    keys_used = []
    for k in sorted_keys:
        if k >= next_index:
            line += '-' * (k - len(line))           # Add dashes before subseq
            line += index_dict[k]['sequence']       # Add subsequence
            next_index = index_dict[k]['end_index'] # Update next_index
            keys_used.append(k)                     # Mark key as used
    for k in keys_used: sorted_keys.remove(k)       # Remove used keys
    line += '-' * (len(seq) - len(line))            # Add trailing dashes
    lines.append(line)                              # Add line to lines

print seq
print '\n'.join(lines)
```

Output:

```
UCAGCUGUCAGUCAUGAUC
UCAGCU--CAGUCA-GAUC
-----UGUCAG--------
```